# Javascript closure syntax

Tags: javascript, closures

What is the difference, pros/cons (if any) between these constructs?

```
 new function(obj) {
     console.log(obj);
 }(extObj);
```

vs

```
 (function(obj) {
     console.log(obj);
 })(extObj);
```

Comment: Could I add - is there a difference between `(function(obj) { .. })(extObj);` and `function(obj) { .. })(extObj);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking at dealing expressly with an immediately-invoked function, then there isn't any real difference between the two, except that the first one will return `this` inside the function, to the outside world, automatically (that is what `new` does), and by default if a different return value is not specified (regular functions return `undefined`).

The rest of the major differences are not really going to matter -- access to the prototype chain is going to be pointless, having the returned `this.constructor` point to the anonymous function would give you access to caching the anonymous function for use at a later time (like removing it from an event listener, if you somehow managed to stick the enclosed function in...  ...that would be a trick in and of itself).

Allowing people to cache your immediately-invoked function as a constructor property of the returned `this` object might be a security-risk...  ...or it might be really useful...  ...in very specific scenarios.

Every-day purposes of firing code in-line -- no real difference.

Comment: i disagree with your last sentence as soon as it comes to the point where you work with variable assignments.

Comment: @Christoph How so?  What I mean to imply is that if there is no variable there to catch the return statement, then there is not going to be much difference at all in what happens inside of the function.  In terms of namespacing modules or whatever else you might do, there can be large ramifications.  If you are inlining immediate, procedural code, outside of the global scope, which is not being returned to a var for later use, then `new` or `(` or `!` are all going to achieve pretty much the same thing, with minimal (practically none) side-effects.

Comment: I agree with your statement though I think it is quite common to store the return value in some way. So i just wanted to point out, that their different behavior about what they return might have major impact.

Comment: It is very common.  But it's also common to enclose procedural code, to avoid adding 2-dozen variables to the global scope, if all you want to do is set event-handlers or bind a known model to a DOM element, et cetera.  Working with the return value, `!`, `new`, `+`, `-`, `~` and `(` all give you something VERY DIFFERENT in what they return.  If you aren't working with the return value, and are relying on doing your whole procedure inside, then you can use any of them to evaluate your function.  In fact, maybe it'd be a good way to indicate which functions do have useful returns.

Answer (score 9):

The first one returns a reference to the newly constructed instance of your anonymous constructor function (= `this`).

The second one returns the return value of the anonymous function. Since your function does not have a return statement, it will implicitly return undefined.

Try the following:

```
var t1 = new function(obj) { console.log(obj); }(extObj);
var t2 =    (function(obj) { console.log(obj); })(extObj);

typeof t1 => "object"
typeof t2 => "undefined"
```

(Btw, `t1.constructor` will return the original function you created `t1` with.)

The difference becomes much clearer, if you add a return statement:

```
var t1 = new function(obj){ return(obj); }("foo");
var t2 =    (function(obj){ return(obj); })("bar");

console.log(t1) => "object"
console.log(t2) => "bar"
```

IMO, this makes the `(function)()` much more useful for the everyday usecase - you assign the returnvalue of the execution of this function to the variable which normally would be what you want if you are working with immediately invoked functions. Especially when having more complex things like (pseudocode):

```
var myNameSpace = (function(){
    /* do some private stuff here*/
    ...
    /* expose parts of your anonymous function by returning them */
    return{
       functionX,
       variable1,
       variable2
    }
}();
```

Basically you can use an arbitrary unary operator to turn the function declaration into an expression, that is immediately invoked. So you could also write:

```
!function(){ /* code */ }();
~function(){ /* code */ }();
-function(){ /* code */ }();
+function(){ /* code */ }();
```

depending on the return statement of your function, these will give different return results. `!` - negate the returnvalue `+|-` evaluate as Number (apply negative sign) `~` apply `bitwise not` to the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Another difference is that the first invocation creates an extra object. Here I've put the names `f` and `o` to denote an objects:

```
var o = new function f(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}(extObj);
```

In second case we still create a function object `f` but we don't create an `o`:

```
(function f(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
})(extObj);
```

A closure is still created but that's cheaper than the actual JavaScript object since it doesn't carry the whole prototype chain or other attributes (like hidden class reference) with it,

Comment: that's not entirely true. you can create an object o in the second case, but since there is no return value, `o` is assigned the implicit return value of that function, which is undefined.

Comment: If you'd write `var o = (function...` then o exists with the assigned value of "undefined" which is pretty much useless because you can't distinguish it from non-existing variables which also return "undefined", but nonetheless `o` exists. You need to write `delete window.o` for that.

Comment: Ah, I see. You mean `o` _as a value_ or named binding exists. Yeah, that's true. However, there's _no extra allocated object_ in a heap that named binding `o` references. Compare that to the first example where both _named binding_ `o` exists and an object in a heap without own properties and a `[[Prototype]]` property is set to `f.prototype` that `o` points to. That's the difference I talk about.