# Bootstrap JS functions definitions

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap JS (I checked version 3.2.0) some function definitions have a plus sign at first and `'use strict';` in the following:

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';
   ...
}
```

`'Use strictly';` as I guess is AMD definition syntax maybe. Can someone explain about this syntax and meaning and where is better to use this pattern?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** It seems the + sign (Or any arbitrary unary operator) uses to turn the function declaration into an expression. Check here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11897575/332420

Comment: That's probably an IIFE, and you missed the parens that call the function `+function(){}()`. `use strict` has nothing to do with AMD, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: Definition is exactly this "+function($){...}(jQuery);" nothing is missing. You can check it yourself here: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: Right, you didn't put the parenthesis in the question, which  makes `+function($){}` non sensical. The plus `+`, or any other unary operators will do `+function(){}(), ~function(){}(), !function(){}(), ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Strict mode makes it easier to write "secure" JavaScript.

Strict mode changes previously accepted "bad syntax" into real errors.

As an example, in normal JavaScript, mistyping a variable name creates a new global variable. In strict mode, this will throw an error, making it impossible to accidentally create a global variable.

In normal JavaScript, a developer will not receive any error feedback assigning values to non-writable properties.

In strict mode, any assignment to a non-writable property, a getter-only property, a non-existing property, a non-existing variable, or a non-existing object, will throw an error."

The + sign is forcing the functions to run automatically, e.g. google is using ! instead

[**MORE**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp)

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of that + sign just before the function keyword. Is it alternate syntax for closure syntax?

Comment: Its forcing function to run automatically, e.g. google is using ! instead +